# save html tag data to sql server in c#

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a table Matrix:

```
Id   Title                           Format
1   Automated Phone plus Links  <span class="avg">{0}%</span><span class="xofy">({1}/{2})</span>
```

The format should be stored in spans.

when we populate it in UI, it will show as:

```
Id   Title                           Format
1   Automated Phone plus Links  {0}%({1}/{2})
```

The problem, when we edit from UI, I am getting error :

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$cph1$grdMatrixType$ctl00$ctl06$ctl02="<span class="avg">{0...").
```

Can somebody advise how to solve this error and save data into database with spans ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
ValidateRequest = "false"
```

to page directive worked for me.